# What's the grammar behind "keep up his demands to be sent heavy weapons"?

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

[This article](https://www.bbc.com/news/live/world-europe-61185469?ns_mchannel=social&ns_source=twitter&ns_campaign=bbc_live&ns_linkname=62651a1477811a20d37c980f%26Zelensky%20to%20put%20weapons%20top%20of%20the%20agenda%20in%20US%20talks%262022-04-24T10%3A09%3A11.235Z&ns_fee=0&pinned_post_locator=urn:asset:53f8849a-2f59-4bc5-865b-a48be4dd0fb1&pinned_post_asset_id=62651a1477811a20d37c980f&pinned_post_type=share) says:

> Something we do know, though, is that Zelensky plans to **keep up his demands to be sent heavy weapons** to help combat the Russian military.

I believe he is demanding that heavy weapons be sent, but I'm not clear what "to be sent" modifies. If it is grammatically correct, is there some kind of word order changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*to be sent* heavy weapons [by the EU or Britain or the US, etc.]

This construction is called **a passive infinitive.**

The way **to do** this job is to do it quickly. [to-infinitive]

The way this job is **to be done** [by you] is quickly. [passive to-infinitive]

Another example:
Active Infinitive:              I do not want **to drive** in a foreign locale, I prefer taxis.

Passive Infinitive:           I prefer **to be driven** in a taxi in a foreign locale.

Taken from this English language teaching site: [passive voice, infinitive](https://www.first-learn.com/passive-infinitive.html#:%7E:text=The%20Passive%20Infinitive%20is%20used,President%20which%20did%20not%20happen.&text=%27Be%27%20is%20added%20after%20%27,used%20for%20making%20Passive%20Voice.)

Comment: I see. In other words, he is demanding that he be sent heavy weapons. Is it right?

Comment: @K.N. Yes, **that's** right.  :) And I hope we do, by the way.